# Backbone click event doesnt trigger

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I was facing a very strange issue. In my hbs code , i have the following piece of code.

```
<a href="#" class="link">Click</a>
```

and my backbone code is as follows

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'clickTest'
],
function(Marionette, Template) {
    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: Template,
        templateHelpers: {},
        events: {
            'click .link' : 'onClickLink'
        },
    onClickLink: function(event ){
         event.preventDefault();
         alert("Hi");
         this.render();
      }
});
```

But on click , I am not able to see any alert..

Im quite new to backbone. can anyone please suggest where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Just guessing, you should call render to allow Backbone bind events

Comment: how to do that ? and where to do that ?

Comment: Try adding `.render()` after `extend()`

Comment: Nope. not working :(.. any other way ?

Comment: u havn't defined the render function! so no use of calling render function. and have you created this view ?

Comment: Is your ``<a href="#" class="link">Click</a>`` inside the template script? Also what is the template engine you're using? can u try : ``"#clickTest"`` instead of ``"clickTest"``?